# Indenting / Spaces layout after a label in Intellij with groovy

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

Intellij Seems to have a default layout like this

```
def foo(int arg) {
    label1:
    for (i in 1..10) {
        label2:
        foo(i)
    }
}
```

How do i change it to

```
def foo(int arg) {
    label1:
        for (i in 1..10) {
            label2:
            foo(i)
        }
}
```

This is required since we want out test layouts to look like this:

```
def 'my test'() {
   given:
       ...
   when:
       ...
   then:
       ...
}
```

ANSWER:
As given below in the answer, I can confirm this works in intellij 13

Comment: Saw this the other day which might be of interest? https://twitter.com/rfletcherEW/status/395161977603248128

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In **Idea Intellij 13+**

`Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Groovy -> Tabs and Indents`

- Label indent: `4`
- Label indent style: `Indent statement after label`

Comment: Thanks, I'm using 12 now which explains why I didnt see it

Comment: This setting works in most cases, but not when inserting a new label above an existing label. For example in a Spock test beginning with an `expect:` label, I want to add a `given:` label above it.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot from `IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.4`
[image]